# Solve the inequality $\sqrt{7+2016x}+49\le 4x^2+\sqrt{2018x}$

Tags: inequality, factoring, alternative-proof

Solve the inequality
$$\sqrt{7+2016x}+49\le 4x^2+\sqrt{2018x}$$

#### My work

1) I used that $A\le B$ and $A,B>0$ $\Leftrightarrow A^2\le B^2$

2) I know the answer [[wolframalpha][1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%287%2B2016x%29%2B49%3C%3D49x%5E2%2Bsqrt%282018x%29)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%287%2B2016x%29%2B49%3C%3D49x%5E2%2Bsqrt%282018x%29)

3) I multyplied both sides $\sqrt{7+2016x}-49$

Is there any simple way how to solve this inequality?

Comment: Why there is $4x^2$ in your text but $49x^2$ in the numerical calculus (WolframAlpha) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course!

It's $$4x^2-49+\sqrt{2018x}-\sqrt{7+2016x}\geq0$$ or
$$(2x-7)\left(2x+7+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2018x}+\sqrt{7+2016x}}\right)\geq0$$ or
$$x\geq\frac{7}{2}.$$

Comment: Can down-voter explain us why did you do it?

Answer (score 2):

If $x \geq 3.5$, $4x^2 \geq 49$ and $7+2016x \leq 2018x$, so the inequality holds.

If $x < 3.5$, then $4x^2 < 49$ and $7+2016x > 2018x$, so the inequality doesn’t hold.

In other words: the inequality holds iff $x \geq 3.5$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the expression is defined only for non-negative $x$. Now,
$$\sqrt{7+2016x}+49\le 4x^2+\sqrt{2018x}$$
$$\iff 4x^2-49 + \sqrt{2018x}-\sqrt{2016x+7}\ge 0$$
$$\iff (2x-7)(2x+7)+\dfrac{2x-7}{\sqrt{2018x}+\sqrt{2016x+7}}\ge 0 $$
$$\iff 2x-7\ge 0$$